# error making upstream request 403 sts vault from aws instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, vault

I have attached one IAM role to the aws instance. The role `my-role` has administrative permissions and sts permissions as well.

I ran the following commands but I get error.

```
export VAULT_ADDR=https://somevaultsite.com
vault login -tls-skip-verify -address=https://somevaultsite.com -method=aws role=my-role
```

```
Error authenticating: Error making API request.

URL: PUT https://somevaultsite.com/v1/auth/aws/login
Code: 400. Errors:

* error making upstream request: received error code 403 from STS: <ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code>
    <Message>The security token included in the request is invalid</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>SOME-REQUEST-ID</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

And when I run the vault command by passing the region I get the error as

```
vault login -tls-skip-verify -address=https://somevaultsite.com -method=aws role=my-role region=us-gov-west-1
```

```
Error authenticating: Error making API request.

URL: PUT https://somevaultsite.com/v1/auth/aws/login
Code: 400. Errors:

* error making upstream request: received error code 403 from STS: <ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-gov-west-1'. </Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>SOME-REQUEST-ID</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

I have bounded the role in vault also.

```
vault write auth/aws/role/my-role auth_type=iam policies=my-policy max_ttl=1h bound_iam_principal_arn=arn:aws-us-gov:iam::xxxxx:role/my-role
```

Note:- I added -tls-skip-verify option because the certificate is not a valid one.

Answer (score 1):

We should set the sts endpoint

```
vault write auth/aws/config/client sts_endpoint=https://sts.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

Then run your login command

```
vault login -tls-skip-verify -address=https://somevaultsite.com -method=aws role=my-role region=us-gov-west-1


Success! You are now authenticated. The token information displayed below is already stored in the token helper. You do NOT need to run "vault login" again. Future Vault requests will automatically use this token.
```

Here's [a Google group link with discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/vault-tool/c/-qluEvA3nnM?pli=1)

Another [link for sts.](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/aws#sts_endpoint)